# Two unity panels at the same time on Ubuntu 16.04. How to close one?

Tags: unity, launcher

Two unity panels are displayed on ubuntu 16.04. It looks like one is displayed above the other. Just like it would be fresh user working above old user. I had some problems with ubuntu 16.04 - launch panel dissapeared. Then I started something and got two panels at once.
Can anyone help me with it, please?

Comment: so the bar with apps that can be launched is duped O_o